# Open a folder using User input in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

At my office we have to regularly open many different job folders on the fly at the same time. I was wondering if there was a script that could allow a user to input the folder name in CMD which will search specified directories on the network drive to open that folder in explorer.

An Example of the folder structure is below:

G/Work_A/2017:

- Folder_A
- Folder_B
- Folder_C
- Folder_D

G/Work_A/2018:

- Folder_E
- Folder_F
- Folder_G
- Folder_H

(I would like to search both 2017 & 2018 folders)

Also all the folders that users input have unique names.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what you want hence why my and @npocmaka answers differ a bit :)

Regardless, This will prompt a user for a foldername, then do a search for that folder and open the folder or all instance of the folder on `G:\` it can be amended to do all drives as well or limited to specific directories.

The point that stood out is the fact that you say each folder is unique, meaning each should only exist once on `G:\` so the first scenario should work.

```
@echo off
set /p promptfolder="Please type the folder you wish to open: "
for /R G:\ %%f in (%promptfolder%) do @IF EXIST %%f explorer.exe "%%f"
```

if you want to specifically limit it to only the 2017 / 2018 directories:

```
@echo off
set /p promptfolder="Please type the folder you wish to open: "
for /R G:\Work_A\2017 %%f in (%promptfolder%) do @IF EXIST %%f explorer.exe "%%f"
for /R G:\Work_A\2018 %%f in (%promptfolder%) do @IF EXIST %%f explorer.exe "%%f"
```

To add it as a loop, to keep the batch open purely use `goto`

```
@echo off
:start
cls
echo Last folder requested: %promptfolder%
set /p promptfolder="Please type the folder you wish to open: "
for /R G:\Work_A\2017 %%f in (%promptfolder%) do @IF EXIST %%f explorer.exe "%%f"
for /R G:\Work_A\2018 %%f in (%promptfolder%) do @IF EXIST %%f explorer.exe "%%f"
cls
goto start
```

Comment: Thank you for your response !
Is there any way keep CMD open to keep prompting for a folder name even after a user has done a search?
Also how can i amend the search to include when users type in part of file name not the entire thing?

Comment: @crazy.Proj.mgr Yes, the script can be amended to loop back, I will edit it.

Comment: @crazy.Proj.mgr see edited bottom solution. Wild card search is possible to search for part of a file, but you are going to possibly cause chaos, if a user types in `A` for arguments sake, it will open any directory from the root you are searching from that has upper `A` or lower `a` in it, that will kill processor and memory quickly.

Comment: Ahh I see .. what about setting a minimum number of letters for the filename wildcard search ?

Comment: @crazy.Proj.mgr Yes, but, then that was not in the scope of the original question :)

Comment: the solution dosnt allow the batch file to loop back to the beginning

Comment: It does. Did you copy it as is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want but you can try this:

```
@echo off
echo --Choose folder to open--

echo G:\Work_A\2017
(echo()
dir /b /a:d G:\Work_A\2017\
echo G:\Work_A\2018\
(echo()
dir /b /a:d G:\Work_A\2018\

set /p "year=Year(2018/2017):"
set /p "folder=Folder:"

if exist "G:\Work_A\%year%\%folder%\" (
  explorer "G:\Work_A\%year%\%folder%\"
)
```